# Ensure that one and only one default is defined for a set

Tags: sql-server

I have a customer table that has a one to many relationship with an address table.
I want to constrain the database so that a customer **with** addresses will always have one (and only one) default address.

I can quite easily add a constraint to ensure that there is only ever one default address for each customer. I am however struggling on how to apply a constraint that ensures that an address is always marked as default.

To summarize:

- A customer is not required to have any addresses.
- If a customer has addresses there must be a default address.
- There must only be one default address per customer.

Here is an example of the problem and some 'unit' tests. I am using a link table to join customers and addresses.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Address]
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Address VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE CustAddress
(
    CustomerId INT,
    AddressId INT,
    [Default] BIT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (AddressId) REFERENCES [Address](Id)
)

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (1, 'Mr Greedy')

INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (1, 'Roly-Poly House, Fatland')
INSERT INTO [Address] VALUES (2, 'Giant Cottage, A Cave')

-- Should succeed
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 2, 0)

DELETE FROM CustAddress

-- Should fail as no default address set
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 1, 0)

DELETE FROM CustAddress

-- Should fail as we end up with no defualt address set
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 2, 0)
UPDATE CustAddress SET [Default] = 0 WHERE CustomerId = 1 AND AddressId = 1

DELETE FROM CustAddress

-- Should fail as we end up with no defualt address set
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO CustAddress VALUES (1, 2, 0)
DELETE FROM CustAddress WHERE CustomerId = 1 AND AddressId = 1
```

Comment: How do you link a customer to an address? Is it via a link table that looks something like (`CustomerId`, `AddressId`)? Or is `CustomerId` in the Address table, along with a `default` column? Regardless, sounds like a good example for a Check Constraint (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) where something like (`select count(*) From table where customerid = @customerid and default = 1) = 1` would be a good place to start.

Comment: A constraint to ensure that there is only ever one default address for each customer can be enforced with a unique partial index: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX OneDefaultAdressPerCustomer ON CustAddress (CustomerId) WHERE [Default] = 1;` But to ensure that there will be one (default) and not none, it's another, more complex issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about changing the schema to

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Address]
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Address VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
)


CREATE TABLE CustDefaultAddress
(
    CustomerId INT PRIMARY KEY, /*Ensures no more than one default*/
    AddressId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Customer(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (AddressId) REFERENCES [Address](Id)
)


CREATE TABLE CustSecondaryAddress
(
    CustomerId INT REFERENCES CustDefaultAddress(CustomerId), 
                   /*No secondary address can be added unless default one exists*/
    AddressId INT REFERENCES [Address](Id),
    PRIMARY KEY(CustomerId, AddressId)
)
```

If there is an additional requirement that an address must not be present as both a primary and secondary address you can enforce this with a helper table and an indexed view.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoRows
  (
     X INT PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT INTO dbo.TwoRows
VALUES      (1),
            (2)

GO

CREATE VIEW V
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT D.AddressId,
         D.CustomerId
  FROM   dbo.CustDefaultAddress D
         JOIN dbo.CustSecondaryAddress S
           ON D.AddressId = S.AddressId
              AND D.CustomerId = S.CustomerId
         CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoRows

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX
  ON V(AddressId, CustomerId)
```

Comment: Very solid and makes perfect sense. Shame it is not very convenient in terms of data manipulation but one must not expect to get everything for free. :)

Comment: @AndriyM - Yes swapping a primary and secondary address will be quite a hassle with this implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In case I didn't miss the requirements, I think that you can enforce the same conditions with an [instead of trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

It's not as elegant as a table design solution, and it will require a bit more complicated trigger I prefer a trigger to be, but will pass all your current tests.

What it actually does is this:

- in case of Insert or Update it will actually validate the entire data set (old and new pairs together to see if each customers has one and only one (notice the sum of default bits) default. In case there are 0 or more than 1 defaults it will raise error.
- in case of Delete it will validate only the remaining addresses per customer to have the same rule (only on default, in an address exists).
- in the end, if there was no error, it will do the same operation it was supposed to do;

The trigger that will work on your table and data would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CustAddress1DefaultAddress
    ON  dbo.CustAddress
    Instead of INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @cnt int, @operation char(1);
    IF exists (select * from inserted)
    and not exists (select * from deleted) --only insert, no delete/update
        select @operation = 'I';
    else if exists (select * from inserted)
        and exists (select * from deleted) --update
        Select @operation = 'U';
    else
        Select @operation = 'D';
    print 'operation = ' + @operation;

    begin try
    if @operation in ('I', 'U')
    begin
        ;with defaultsPerCustAdd(SumDefault, CustomerId)
        as (
            select sum (x.[Default]), x.CustomerId
            from (
                select i.CustomerId, cast(i.[Default] as tinyint) as [Default]
                from inserted as i
                union all
                select ca.CustomerId, cast(ca.[Default] as tinyint) as [Default]
                from dbo.CustAddress as ca
                join inserted i on i.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId
                and i.AddressId != ca.AddressId
            ) as x
            group by x.CustomerId
        )
        select *
        from defaultsPerCustAdd as d
        where d.SumDefault = 0
        OR d.SumDefault > 1;
        set @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
    end
    else -- Delete
    begin
        ;with defaultsPerCustAdd(SumDefault, CustomerId)
        as (
            select sum (x.[Default]), x.CustomerId
            from (
                select ca.CustomerId, cast(ca.[Default] as tinyint) as [Default]
                from dbo.CustAddress as ca
                join deleted d on d.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId
                and d.AddressId != ca.AddressId
            ) as x
            group by x.CustomerId
        )
        select *
        from defaultsPerCustAdd as d
        where d.SumDefault = 0
        OR d.SumDefault > 1;
        set @cnt = @@ROWCOUNT;
    end;

    if @cnt > 0
        raiserror('error when validating one default address per customer', 16, 1)

    if @operation = 'I'
        insert dbo.CustAddress(CustomerId, AddressId, [Default])
        select i.CustomerId, i.AddressId, i.[Default]
        from inserted as i
    else if @operation = 'U'
        update ca
        set [default] = i.[default]
        from dbo.CustAddress as ca
        join inserted as i on i.AddressId = ca.AddressId and i.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId
    else if @operation = 'D'
        delete ca
        from dbo.CustAddress as ca
        join deleted as d on d.AddressId = ca.AddressId and d.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId

    end try
    begin catch
        print 'error when validating one default address per customer';
    end catch;
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Marian, It is nice to have an alternative solution especially one that does not involve changing the schema as I have come across this situation maintaining a legacy app.

Comment: @GrahamAmbrose you're welcome. This was exactly my thought, you can't always change the system. While it's better to have an elegant design upfront, sometimes you just need something that works.

Comment: +1 You'd probably want an explicit `WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)` in there though in case run [under snapshot isolation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/26/Snapshot_and_integrity_part_2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

dash suggested that a Check Constraint

> something like (select count(*) From table where customerid =
>   @customerid and default = 1) = 1

could be used so I have created this answer.

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumberOfCustomerDefaultAddresses
(
    @CustomerId INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM CustAddress
        WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
        AND [Default] = 1
    )
END
GO

ALTER TABLE CustAddress ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_DefaultAddress CHECK (dbo.NumberOfCustomerDefaultAddresses(CustomerId) = 1)
```

This works in that it stops inserts that would result in no default address being set. But it **fails** to detect updates that change the default flag and deletes that remove the default record.

Comment: Martin, I created this answer so I could highlight problems I had with it. Something that is hard to do in comments. If you have a solution then please post an answer as I can not see how filter indexes can be used.

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX ON CustAddress(CustomerId) WHERE [Default] = 1`

Comment: Ah actually that ensures "no more than one". Not "exactly one". To ensure exactly one you need to change the schema and add a `NOT NULL`-able column to `Customer` for the default address.

Comment: How would a NOT NULL-able column work when a customer does not have any addresses?

Comment: It wouldn't. I see my initial scan of the question missed a few important aspects!

Comment: I have updated the questions to try and make all the requirements clearer.

Comment: It was clear enough already. My mistake was looking at this answer and inferring what the question probably was based on that (as the question "how to ensure no more than one default" comes up frequently)