# Check for specific value in another table as a constraint

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as follows.

Table Car

```
Manufacturer    Model    ApprovalStatus
Toyota          SE       Approved
Toyota          C-HR     Testing
Prius           XLE      Approved
Hyundai         NEXO     Testing
```

Table Dealership

```
ParkingSpace    Manufacturer    Model
F1              Toyota          SE
F2              Toyota          SE
F3              Toyota          C-HR 
...             ...             ...
```

I want to add a constraint on adding data into the dealership table based on the manufacturer and model. Only manufacturers and models with an approved status should be added into the Dealership table. If a user tries to enter an existing model and manufacturer with a status that is not approved, it should not let them.

How do I check the `ApprovalStatus` value based on the foreign key `Manufacturer` and `Model` and add this as a constraint.

Comment: Hmm I see, is there no way to structure this without separating the tables?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was under the assumption that this was something I could do with some combination of check and join. I think I'll just take your prior advice and separate them and keep it straightforward.

Comment: that might cause other issues though dependant on how frequently your queries need to deal with the entire set of cars - both approved and unapproved and possible anomalies with `Manufacturer,Model` showing up in both places. I've added an answer with the three options that spring to mind for me

Comment: TBH the more I think about it the more I favour the indexed view approach. This requires no schema changes to split up the Cars and no need to add redundant unique constraints/columns, the indexed view will also require no storage as it will always be empty

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a *great* way of doing this. There is no concept of applying foreign keys with some additional conditions. The three options that spring to mind for me are below.

### Separate tables

Probably the easiest way *of fulfilling this specific goal* is to just create two tables - one with Approved Cars and one with the rest.

The primary key of `ApprovedCars` would be `(Manufacturer,Model)` and then you can just create a foreign key to that table.

There is still some possibility of anomalies with this approach though - such as a `Manufacturer,Model` being in both tables. And it will add complexity to queries needing to access the entire set of cars.

### Indexed View

You want to assert that the below query always returns no rows

```
SELECT C.Manufacturer, C.Model
FROM   Car C
JOIN   Dealership D
ON     C.Manufacturer = D.Manufacturer
       AND C.Model = D.Model
WHERE  ApprovalStatus IS NULL OR ApprovalStatus <> 'Approved'
```

You can create a helper table with two rows and cross join onto that to multiply out any violations then put the whole lot in an indexed view with a unique constraint on it ([detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704466/ensure-that-one-and-only-one-default-is-defined-for-a-set/17720851#17720851)).

### Supertype/Subtype pattern

I assume your existing PK on `Car` is `(Manufacturer,Model)`.

You could add a logically redundant **additional** unique constraint on `(Manufacturer,Model,ApprovalStatus)` then add `ApprovalStatus` to the `Dealership` table with a check constraint that it must equal "Approved" and have a foreign key referencing all three columns.